# Should I choose sub-directories over sub-domains in this case?

Tags: seo, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm developing an application at the moment which shows local content based on location.

Since the site is intended for local users, there won't be much need to change domain.

For example: someone from London visiting `london.mysite.com` will receive only London-related content and would not necessarily be interested in anything on `edinburgh.mysite.com`.

The whole subdomain vs. sub-directory thing has been haunting me though and I'm not sure if this approach is best or if we'd be better with `mysite.com/edinburgh`.

Can any SEO gurus out there lend some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Gavin Morrice: From a hosting and development point of view, sub-directories are so much easier and quicker to maintain (especially if you're not on a dedicated server). While trying to find the latest information on which method is the preferred or best one, the general sense I get is that (as far as Google is concerned), it really doesn't matter anymore. *If you build it, they will come*.

It's about content; it has always been about content. If you can sort out relevance and structure, whether your articles about London are on `london.mysite.com` or `mysite.com/london/`, doesn't make much of a difference and tales of sub-domains diluting Google's PageRank from the main site remain tales and certainly don't seem to be true anymore.

Comment: Matt Cutts agrees: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have complete control over the server and code so implementation is not an issue for me. I also find it more logical to organise the data by subdomain. Given that the SEO value of each is the same, I'll stick with my original choice

Answer (score 3):

[There is no difference between the two as far as SEO goes](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/). Use which ever one is easier for you to work with.

Comment: Ah - I had just found that link through another site. Thanks for the advice :)