# Wordpress installation - Subdomain or as folder?

Tags: seo, wordpress, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subdomain versus subdirectory](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/subdomain-versus-subdirectory)

I got a client portfolio website and he opens a Wordpress blog with articles related to his profession. What the best for SEO - install it as subdomain or as folder?

```
www.myclientsite.com/blog/
```

or

```
blog.myclientsite.com
```

This is fresh domain without any previous content.

Answer (score 1):

See [Should I choose sub-directories over sub-domains in this case?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12759/should-i-choose-sub-directories-over-sub-domains-in-this-case/12761#12761)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can have any important SEO impact, I think it's more a question of personal taste. Also, take note that it's much quicker and easier to just create a subfolder.